# MacBook Pro - Issue with Indenting on Pages

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, pages

I have been using Pages for a lot of my academic writing, but sometimes, I have issues with indents appearing mysteriously when typing out a references list for an essay. I always use a hanging indent, but what is happening is not intentional. For example, when I copy and paste text (a reference for the reference list), half of the entire text (starts about halfway into the URL for the reference) splits and drops below itself - without any discernable reason; no indentation shows on the Layout section, meaning nothing is above 0.0 for First, Left, or Right. I have tried everything from re-copying and pasting the desired text to highlighting the text to see if any clues show on the Layout section - to see if something shows up.
[image]

Comment: it is to long to fit in one line, so it had to break it up somewhere

Comment: Hmm. If this is occurring due to something outside of my control - then I suppose I should not worry about it; however, my concern is that I could get points off due to the format not looking uniform with the other reference.

Comment: it is one continuous line, and the best breaking point was after the `/` , so reason for you to worry